# RobotFramework Selenium: How to select multiple options from multiselect drop down list?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, multi-select

In Robot Framework(with selenium/python)how to select multiple options from multiselect dropdown list on a webpage?

Comment: I think you should give us more detail than this.

Comment: I am using Robot Framework with Selenium Library. As a test requirement, i have a dropdown on the web page where i need to select more than one options from a single drop down(E.g. Selecting preferred locations from a dropdown list of all applicable cities in US). Manually we can do using a combination of Ctrl+click on multiple items in that list. Can't find any direct keyword in SeleniumLibrary to implement this.

Comment: in Selenium webdriver, we can use ActionChains to simulate Hold mouse key+mouse clicks to multiple elements of the same dropdown list but not sure how to do the same in Robot Framework

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of `Select from list by value`, `Select from list by index` or `Select from list by label` keywords from the [SeleniumLibrary](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20From%20List%20By%20Index).

Ex: If you want to select the first 2 values from the multi-select box use the below code

```
*** Test Cases ***
Select multiple values from list
    Select from list by index    ${MultiSelectBoxLocator}    0    1
```

Comment: Hi Sameem,thx for ur response.I tried this option earlier also and theoretically it worked.But the application i m using is either flawed or tricky.Try selecting multiple values from dropdown list on (https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-select-dropdown-demo.html) and then click 'Get All Selected' button.Manaually we get a tag as response containing all selected items(E.g. 'Options selected are : all items u have selected' but when i automate this, only the last selected item is displayed in the message instead of all selected items. Please try this once and let me know ur thoughts.

Comment: I tried to do it manually. Even if I select multiple values and click 'Get All Selected', only the last value in the list is displayed in the `Options selected are` section. Seems like an issue with the page itself.